# Vue.js fix async mounted() run before watcher

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, mount

I have my data return properly, I'm able to print `{{this.point0}}` or `{{point1}}`in template with no problem.

But it seems like I can't use `this.point0` under `async mounted()`, I'm not sure that the value remains 0 or null, I try to create `let p0 = this.point0;`, but the `p0` also doesn't work.The `datapresent` keep give me no value

Can check out my code here https://jsfiddle.net/1eahf26q/

```
  props: ["breedKey", "time"],
  computed: {
    topic() {
      return this.breedKey;
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      point0: [],
      point1: [],
      point20: [],
    };
  },

  watch: {
   async breedKey (newVal, oldVal)  {
       try {

      var url = new URL('https://www.mustavi.com/TimeSeries/?param1=China&param2=00');
      var search_params = url.searchParams;

      search_params.set('param1', this.topic);
      search_params.set('param2', '2020-04-13');

      url.search = search_params.toString();
      var new_url = url.toString();
      console.log(new_url);
      this.promise = axios.get(new_url);
      const res = await this.promise;

      this.point0 = res.data.data[0].Freq;
      this.point1 = res.data.data[1].Freq;
      this.point20 = res.data.data[20];
   }
  },

  async mounted() {
    await this.promise;

    let p0 = this.point0;
    let p1 = this.point1;

    const datapresent = [p0, p1, this.point1,];
    const datapast = []; 
    },
})
```

Comment: `mounted` is running before your watcher has gotten the data.

Comment: this.promise is not defined, there is no promise to wait for on the mounted method. You need to define it.

Comment: Will adding `promise:[]` in data return help? How to force it to wait before mount?

Comment: I try `immediate: true,` is still the same

Comment: Why do you want to use `this.point0` in the `mounted` hook ?

Comment: my child component is for plot a time series line chart, each this.point is the frequency

Comment: have to use the data set in renderchart